# Chemical potential derived from Landau free energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

If Landau free energy is neither Gibb's or Helmholtz free energy, why we can say:

$$\mu_i=\partial_i f,$$

where f is the Landau free energy density, e.g. $$f=A\psi^2+B\psi^4+|\nabla \psi|^2,$$ which uses $\psi$ as an order parameter?